Converting raw data to XML string and parsing it in R
I am bringing in some data from a SQL Server database into R using the odbc package which includes a raw field that needs to be converted to an XML string and then parsed (i.e. each record has a separate XML in it). Earlier I was casting it to string in the SQL itself as -
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), xml_content) AS xml_string
FROM ....

and then parsing the xml_string in R using the xml2 package -
xml_list <- as_list(
    read_xml(xml_string, 
             options = c("HUGE")
             )
    )

but that adds a lot of processing time to the query as it's bringing in thousands of records and the XML strings are big. I want to perform both the casting and the parsing in R itself to reduce the query processing time. I'm unable to find the right function to do the casting as whatever I try only returns a fragment of the XML string and not the entire string. I've tried -
#Method 1 -
raw_data <- readBin(binary_data, what = "raw", n=length(binary_data))
rawToChar(raw_data)

#Method 2 -
iconv(rawToChar(as.raw(binary_data)), from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")

#Method 3 - 
decoded_data <- base64decode(binary_data)
xml_string <- rawToChar(decoded_data)

but they don't seem to yield the entire XML string for me. I'm an R rookie, so would like some advice as to where I'm going wrong and how to remedy this. Thanks!

As R does not have an builtin type for XML, it has to rely on the textual (or any other form understood by R) representation.
Unfortunately, you did not show us how you retrieved binary_data but I guess that you tried to cast the XML to binary first?
Anyhow, this approach works as expected:
SQL Server
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##funwithxml;
CREATE TABLE ##funwithxml (
  x XML
);

DECLARE @xml XML = '<employee>
  <firstname type="textbox">Jimmy</firstname>
  <lastname type="textbox">Bischoff</lastname>
  <email type="textbox">jimmy0@adventure-works.com</email>
  <title type="textbox">Database Engineer</title>
</employee>';

INSERT INTO ##funwithxml VALUES(@xml);

R
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "<myserver>")
con %>% 
   tbl("##funwithxml") %>% 
   mutate(x = sql("CAST(x AS NVARCHAR(MAX))")) %>% ## do explicit convert
   pull(x) %>% 
   xml2::read_xml()
# {xml_document}
# <employee>
# [1] <firstname type="textbox">Jimmy</firstname>
# [2] <lastname type="textbox">Bischoff</lastname>
# [3] <email type="textbox">jimmy0@adventure-works.com</email>
# [4] <title type="textbox">Database Engineer</title>

Of course, conceptionally you still do the conversion on the SQL Server side, but in my opinion that's the only way as you do not have an XML data type in R. You could also convert to VARBINARY and convert it to a string before passing it to read_xml, but you need some sort of (SQL-) server side conversion do overcome the issue of not existing data types in R.
